# infinite sum can't be natural

Tags: number-theory, collatz-conjecture

Take the following sum.
$$f(k,p)=\frac{\sum_{i=1}^k2^{p_{i-1}}3^{k-i}}{2^{p_k}-3^k}$$
where the set $p$ is an arbitrarily increasing set of positive integers. Explain why $f(k,p)$ is only natural when $f(k,p)=1$.

So far I've come up with using long division to get that
$$f(k,p)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{i=1}^k\frac{3^{nk-i}}{2^{np_k-p_{i-1}}}$$

And that turns out to just be an infinite sum of incrementing powers of 3 over arbitrarily increasing powers of 2. So, effectively,
$$f(k,p)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{3^{n-1}}{2^{p_n}}=\frac{1}{\sqrt[n]{2^{p_n}}-3}$$
$$\therefore p_n=n\log_2\Big(\frac{1}{f(k,p)}+3\Big)$$

But the above just shows that every $p_n$ could be that and the algebra would work. But, we need $p$ to be a sequence of positive integers, so in reality, it can't be defined by the $p_n$ formula above.

Again, the question is why can't $f(k,p)$ be a natural number greater than 1 when we have the restriction on $p$?

Comment: I have a hard time understanding exactly what you ask, but $$p_n=2n-1$$ leads to $$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{3^{n-1}}{2^{2n-1}} = 2$$

Comment: Yes that is true, thanks. I have now edited the question and added context.

Comment: I didn't follow your derivations so far. But the first formula (when $a=2^{p_k}$ is the next perfect power above $b=3^k$)  occurs in the question of existence of non-trivial cycles in the Collatz-problem. So I think for this case you won't find some proof for your conjecture. If  $a$ is the next perfect power of $2$ *below* $b$ then you'll find $3$ solutions (the three cycles in the negative numbers) If $a$ and $b$ differ in other ways I don't know - but then it is unrelated to the Collatz-problem.

Comment: Could you link me or explain why $2^{p_k}$ being the next perfect power above $3^k$ occurs in the question of the existence of non-trivial cycles in the Collatz-problem?

Comment: You edited the question after I answered it, making my answer not match, then reasked the question [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2957951/why-cant-this-infinite-sum-be-natural).  Please roll this one back to the original.

Comment: @RossMillikan
I apologise, you were correct that my original question was false, which claimed that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{3^{n-1}}{2^{p_n}}$$
could'nt be a positive integer greater than 1. I edited it because I should have started before, asking why $f(k,p)$ cannot be a positive integer greater than 1.

Comment: If you could verify this was correct then you could indeed prove non-existence of non-trivial cycles, but I assume may people have already tried this, I know I have and I am hardly Erdos. The main problem comes with have to deal with "arbitrary" variables. This reflects the conjecture's chaotic nature. There are simply too many variables that need to be accounted for.

Comment: I just wanted to point out that the exponent $p_k$ for $2$ on the denominator is wrong when specifically talking about cycles in the conjecture as that would mean you only divide by $2$ once more than you do $3n+1$.

Answer (score 0):

The statement is false.  The sum can be any positive integer desired.  Even more, we can start with any desired finite sequence $p_n$ and extend it to form any sum that we have not already exceeded.

If our target is $N$, just take $p_n$ the smallest number greater than $p_{n-1}$ that leaves the sum below $N$.  The sum is bounded above and monotonic, so it converges.  If $p_n=p_{n-1}+1$ the $n^{th}$ term is $\frac 32$ times the $n-1^{st}$ term so we can make the terms get larger and larger until we get close.

For example, if we want to represent $4$ the $p_n$ start
$$1,2,3,5,7,11,15,19,21,27,30,33,35,43,48,51,54$$ by which point we are at $3.999999998$.  If $s_{n}$ is the sum of the first $n$ terms we have $$p_n=\max\left(p_{n-1}+1,\left\lceil \log_2 \left(\frac {3^{n-1}}{N-s_{n-1}}\right)\right\rceil\right)$$

Comment: Thank you, yes I see that I rushed the setting out of the question. As it is you are correct. This comes from my study of the Collatz Conjecture.